# How to set a Key Vault secret from Azure Function app in the same resource group?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-powershell, azure-keyvault, azure-function-app

I would like to set up an Azure Function, which would run every 4h, retrieve a JWK from an URL (it is not the one I show below) and save it into a Key Vault as a secret.

When I try the Powershell code at the command line, it just works:

```
PS C:\> $x5c = (Invoke-WebRequest https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/v2.0/keys |
>> ConvertFrom-Json |
>> Select-Object -expand keys |
>> Where-Object -Property kid -Eq SsZsBNhZcF3Q9S4trpQBTByNRRI) |
>> Select-Object -expand x5c
PS C:\> $secretvalue = ConvertTo-SecureString $x5c -AsPlainText -Force
PS C:\> $secret = Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName my-keyvault -Name 'MyLittleSecret' -SecretValue $secretvalue
```

and I can see the secret in the Key Vault:

[image: key vault screenshot]

However when I try to set up a timed Azure Function, then nothing happens, when I click "Run":

[image: function app]

I suppose that being a Function newbie I am looking in the wrong place for the logs... But even if I find them, is that the correct way to do my task?

1. Does Azure PowerShell work in a Function?
2. Does it require a `Login-AzAccount` first?

Comment: Hi Joy, thanks for your reply! I need few days to test your very detailed answer (already upvoted)

Comment: Well, good luck, any problem feel free to let me know.;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does Azure PowerShell work in a Function?

Yes, it will work.

> Does it require a Login-AzAccount first?

No, you don't need to do that.

---

For more details, please follow the steps below.

1.Make sure you created the function app with the settings like below.

[image]

2.After creating the function app, navigate to the `Identity` of the app in the portal, enable the System assigned MSI like below.

[image]

3.Navigate to your keyvault in the portal -> `Access policies` -> `Add Access Policy` -> search for your function name(the MSI has the same name as your function) and add it with correct secret permissions.

[image]

4.In the function, no need to login manually, it will login with the MSI automatically, just use the command below, it works fine on my side.

```
param($Timer)

$x5c = (Invoke-WebRequest https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/v2.0/keys | ConvertFrom-Json |Select-Object -expand keys |Where-Object -Property kid -Eq SsZsBNhZcF3Q9S4trpQBTByNRRI) | Select-Object -expand x5c
$secretvalue = ConvertTo-SecureString $x5c -AsPlainText -Force
$secret = Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName joykeyvault -Name 'MyLittleSecret' -SecretValue $secretvalue
Write-Host $secret.Name
```

[image]

Check the keyvault:

[image]

Comment: I have followed your sugggestion and have added the MSI to the keyvaul access policies, with the permissions to get, list, set secrets. For some reason when I click Function -> Code + Test -> Run, then the Logs only show "Connecting to Application Insights..." and Output "202 Accepted", but nothing else happens and there is no new secret created.

Comment: @AlexanderFarber Could you try my complete script, see if `$secret.Name` will be written out? And there may be some delay, could you check the keyvualt later again? Or please create a new powershell function app to have a try, enable the app insight, there are some bugs in the new UI.

Comment: I have tried again today and it has worked. Thank you for the detailed guide. Do you know if there is an az cli command for creating the System assigned Identity? Is it done by [az managedapp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/managedapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-managedapp-create) ? I am asking because my function app is to be created by an Azure pipeline

Comment: @AlexanderFarber Use this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp/identity?view=azure-cli-latest#az-functionapp-identity-assign

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative approach is to get it from keyvault at runtime and store it in configuration and then use configuration values in the code.
Refer : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references

Configuration will be something like this
UsernameKV:
@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://myvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/mysecret/ec96f02080254f109c51a1f14cdb1931)
PasswordKV:
@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://myvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/mysecret/ec96f02080254f109c51a1f14cdb1931)

Answer (score 0):

```
Does Azure PowerShell work in a Function?
```

Yes you can use [`Powershell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-vs-code?pivots=programming-language-powershell) to create Azure function. And [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell) should help you

```
Does it require a Login-AzAccount first?
```

Yes if you need some logic related to Azure resources you need it.

When it comes to actual question, i think you need to zip the function and upload it to azure function app,

## Zip the folder to upload the Azure Function

```
Compress-Archive -Path * -DestinationPath Function1.zip
```

Comment: I am confused by your answer: 1. Why do I need to zip my code if I have already entered it in the browser (please see my screenshot) and clicked "Save"? 2. How can I use `Login-AzAccount` in a timed Function, without me entering the password?

Comment: i think i should have been more clear, i wanted you to verify the content is same or not. You can do it by downloading the content and comparing that with the local one. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push#deployment-zip-file-requirements

Comment: if you use Managed Identity within your Azure Function, you don't even have to manually connect to your Azure Account